# For loop with cor.test() in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am new to R and am trying to run the following loop:

```
    CorrData <- read.csv("F:/CorrelationDataSets)
    HIVNYears2=list()
    par( mfrow=c(3,3))
    for (i in unique(CorrData$Year))
   {  x=as.numeric(CorrData[CorrData$Year==i,]$NumVisits)
      y=as.numeric(CorrData[CorrData$Year==i,]$HIVN )
      plot(x , y , col="red" , type="p" , pch=16 , main=i )
          HIVNYears2[[i]]<-cor.test(x, y, method="spearman",na.action=na.exclude, by=CorrData$Year)
        }
HIVNYears2
```

I have 93 counties and data for all of them for the past 7 years. In this loop, I am trying to run correlations by year--specifically for the number of HIV cases and the number of visits to the healthcare facility.

When I run this code, it gives me 2016 results, when I am only wanting/expecting 7--one Spearman Correlation for each of the seven years that data was collected between the two variables. The plots look as expected, but the results of the cor.test() do not.

Would you be able to help identify the error in the loop?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Instead of doing multiple cor.test in a loop, you could look at `corr.test` from psych. I generally find it to be a bit slow, it depends on how many comparisons you're performing.

Comment: `corr.test` is indeed a helpful thing to know about, but it works on multiple variables, not on subsets of the data.

Comment: Also, there's no `by` option for `cor.test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's giving you 2016 results, I think it's putting the results in the 2010 - 2017 indices of the output vector. That is,

```
HIVNYears2[[2010]] <- [whatever]
```

makes the result 2010 units long, and puts [whatever] in the 2010'th spot.

There are a number of ways to improve your code, but simply to fix this problem, make Year a character vector instead of numeric.

```
CorrData$Year <- as.character(CorrData$Year)
```

The most "base R" way to improve the code is to split the data set and then run the code on each part.

```
CorrDataSplit <- split(CorrData, CorrData$Year)
for(subdata in CorrDataSplit) { [run code] }
```

Further improvement would potentially to use `lapply`, which is usually preferred instead of the for loop, or the new `tidyverse` packages, which have lots of options for doing work like this.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your explanation! Your first solution to fix my problem worked--simply changing it to a character vector. I will look into the other methods that you mentioned. I have only been learning R for 2 months, so I am definitely looking to improve my code!

Comment: Great, glad to help. Please click the check so that others can easily see that your question has been answered.